# PHP & uploading to database

Tags: php, database, file, mysqli, upload

I need some help with uploading video files into a database.

When I'm uploading my script succeeds but nothing happens in the database, no files.

```
<html>
<head>

<title> upload </title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
</head>
<body>


  <?php
    include 'connect.php';

  ?>

<div id='box'>
  <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <?php
    if (isset($_FILES['video'])) {

    $name = $_FILES['video']['name'];
    $type = explode('.', $name);
    $type = end($type);
    $size = $_FILES['video']['size'];
    $random_name = rand();
    $tmp = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];
    if ($type != 'MOV' && $type != 'mov' && $type != 'QucikTime-film'){
      $message = "Video Format Not Supported !";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'videos/'.$random_name.'.'.$type);

      {

             mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT into videos VALUES (''. '$name', 'videos/$random_name.$type')");
               $message = "Successfully Uploaded ! ";
              }

                 }
              echo "$message <br/><br/>";
                }
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

My connect.php should be all set

```
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost:3306");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "root");
define("DB_DATABASE", "video_system");

$connect = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER , DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
```

Comment: Do you need to upload files or filenames? Because in your current version of code you're just putting filenames in

Comment: ***need some help with uploading video files into a database.*** You can't upload file. only path and name.

Comment: Thanks. I just added my full code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get that what you are searching simply...
https://www.phptpoint.com/upload-video-in-php/

The basic thing for upload image/video/file in php is first you have to write the path where it will be stored..

Comment: Thanks. I didn't use that because of the mysql didn't work.

Comment: then what you are using?

Comment: I'm using mysqli